# How to return a NumPy array with m rows of n random integer values between 0 and 99 in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, random

I am trying to return an array that takes m, rows, of n, a random integer n, however, I am not sure how to do this. Do I need to set m = to random user input? And n = random integer 0-99. This is the code I have however, instead of me telling the array to be 6 rows of 7 random numbers how do I replace it with m and n and have it work using a random number of rows and integers?

```
import numpy as np
def gen_matrix(m,n):
m= 
return np.random.rand(6,7)*100
random_matrix = numpy.random.randint(0,max_val, 
(<num_rows>,<num_cols>))
```

Comment: I don't get the question. What's wrong with `numpy.random.randint(0,max_val + 1, size=(m, n))`?

Comment: I'm not sure from your question if `n` is the number of random integers in each row, the upper bound for the random integers, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the following:**

```
import numpy as np

def gen_matrix(m,n):
    matrix = np.random.randint(0,99, size=(m, n))
    return matrix
```

**Test it:**

```
my_matrix = gen_matrix(5,5)

print(my_matrix)
```

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question. I was confused because I didn't know size = (m, n)  would work. I thought n had to be assigned a random integer number.